# Command to prevent suspend while another command executes?

Tags: linux, suspend

Is there a command to prevent the suspending of a system while another command executes?

For example; lets say I have an upload that I want to complete but it gets interrupted because of my machine suspending. Is there a command that I can use to execute another command that prevents my machine from sleeping until the command finishes?

Comment: Consider including distro you're using in tags or the question as this might be slightly distro-dependent thing.

Comment: @josten - SamiLaine is right, the solution might be dependent, better to include this info than not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write my own tool to do this using DBus; so far it seems to work just fine: https://bitbucket.org/josten/runt

Answer (score 1):

#### GNOME2

If you're using a distro that uses a desktop derived from GNOME 2 you can use the application [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) to control when your system's screensaver and auto suspend kick in.

#### GNOME3

For GNOME 3 based distros you can use this GNOME shell extension, also called Caffeine.

- [Caffeine GNOME shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/)
- [gnome-shell-extension-caffeine github repository](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-caffeine)

*Applet screenshot - shows enabled/disabled*

[image: ss of caffeine]

**NOTE:** You can use it to control which applications will block the screen/suspend from occurring.

*Applet's config dialog*

[image: ss of config]

#### setterm

*untested by me*

**NOTE:** I found this method in the [comments of a Linux Journal article on Caffeine](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-keep-your-monitor-awake-caffeine). Your mileage may vary with this solution, from what I understand, `setterm` is for controlling similar features such as blanking the screen and powersaving, but from a console perspective, not an X windows desktop.

```
$ setterm -powersave off -blank 0
```

For permanent change Add to your `~/.Xinitrc` file or whatever dot file is approprite for running these commands as part of your environment:

```
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
xset s off
```

#### References

- [Display Power Management Signaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling)
- [Linux disable screen blanking i.e. preventing screen going blank](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disable-screen-blanking-screen-going-blank.html)

Comment: `setterm` is just for ttys, I'm pretty sure it won't have any effect in X.

Comment: @ChrisDown - that's what I thought too, was trying to investigate it further, on the off chance. I added a blurb about it only being for console.

Comment: @ChrisDown - research seems to be backing up our understanding, I see no indications that it'll work for anything but console/tty.